# Task scheduler hibernate after 18:00 with task repeat issue

Tags: windows, windows-11, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

My use case:
Hibernate computer after 18:00 if it's being idle for 10 minutes.
But if I turn it on after hibernation I would like this task to be repeated every 10 minutes till next morning.

## My setup

### Trigger

[image: Trigger]

### Conditions

[image: Conditions]

### Settings

[image: Settings]

## Issue

It turns off even after 12 hours are passed.
Issue:
[image: Issue]